# Range.toString() not returning HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, range

With this code below, I can get all contents from the starting of a contenteditable div to the caret position. But the issue I am having is `range.toString()` don't return html tags like line breaks, it just return only plain text.

Please I need to get all contents including the html tags. Below is my code:

```html
<div id="divTxt" contenteditable>Hello, I am John<br>Nice to meet you</div>
<button onclick="getWordPrecedingCaret(document.getElementById('divTxt'))">Click</button>
```

```js
function getWordPrecedingCaret(containerEl){
    var preceding = "",
        sel,
        range,
        precedingRange;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
            preceding = range.toString();
        }
    } else if ((sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        range = sel.createRange();
        precedingRange = range.duplicate();
        precedingRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
        precedingRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", range);
        preceding = precedingRange.text;
    }

    var words = range.toString().trim();
    console.log(words);
}
```

This is the result am having

```
Hello, I am JohnNice to meet you
```

But this is the result I need instead

```
Hello, I am John<br>Nice to meet you
```

Answer (score 1):

Use instead of [Range#toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/toString) rather [Range#startContainer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/startContainer) which returns a [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node).

You can then access the `innerHTML` of the Node which will give you 
`Hello, I am John<br>Nice to meet you` like desired.

Here a snippet:

```js
function getWordPrecedingCaret(containerEl){
    var preceding = "",
        sel,
        range,
        precedingRange;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
            preceding = range.toString();
        }
    } else if ((sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        range = sel.createRange();
        precedingRange = range.duplicate();
        precedingRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
        precedingRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", range);
        preceding = precedingRange.text;
    }

    var html = range.startContainer.innerHTML;
    console.log(html);
    
}
```

```html
<div id="divTxt" contenteditable>Hello, I am John<br>Nice to meet you</div>
<button onclick="getWordPrecedingCaret(document.getElementById('divTxt'))">Click</button>
```

Comment: Okay... But read the question well. I don't want the whole html content. I just want the HTML content up till the care position or the cursor

Comment: @KANAYOAUGUSTINUG Did you find any solution for this, as this will not work for our case?